# OpenAI Gym complex Dictionary observation space : shape, flattening and dimensions

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, reinforcement-learning, tf.keras

I am new to Reinforcement Learning and trying to implement DQN using Keras, TF2.0 and Sequential model. For the problem at hand, I have an observation space that uses gym.spaces.Dict

```
self.observation_space = spaces.Dict({
    "elem_1": spaces.Discrete(64),
    "elem_2": spaces.Tuple((
        spaces.Dict({
            "prop_1": spaces.Discrete(100),
            "prop_2": spaces.Discrete(10),
            "prop_3": spaces.Discrete(4),
            "prop_4": spaces.Discrete(4),
            "prop_5": spaces.Discrete(4),
            "prop_6": spaces.Discrete(4),
            "prop_7": spaces.Discrete(4),
            "prop_8": spaces.Discrete(4),
        }),)*64
    )
})
```

My questions are as below:

1. What is correct way to flatten this Dictionary observation space : `gym.spaces.utils.flatten_space`? When I count the value manually, I get only 513 elements (1 + (64 * 8)). But `gym.spaces.utils.flatten_space` gives around 8801. I am unable to understand that.
2. If #1, how does the numpy array equivalent look like for this observation space? As far as I understand, when making an observation in the above environment space, the dict will need to be converted to numpy array when calling the epsilon greedy function. ex.

In below functions, I keep falling back to same issue of expected 3D input, found (1, 1) array

def replay(self, replay_buffer, batch_size, model, target_model):
# As long as the buffer has not enough elements we do nothing
if len(replay_buffer) < batch_size:
return

```
# Take a random sample from the buffer with size batch_size
samples = random.sample(replay_buffer, batch_size) 

# to store the targets predicted by the target network for training
target_batch = []  

# # Efficient way to handle the sample by using the zip functionality
zipped_samples = list(zip(*samples))  
states, actions, rewards, new_states, dones = zipped_samples  

states = np.array(states)
states = states.reshape((batch_size, 1, 513))
targets = target_model.predict(states)


# Predict Q-Values for all new states from the sample
new_states = np.array(new_states)

# new_states = new_states.reshape((-1, 1, 513))
new_states = new_states.reshape((batch_size, 1, 513))
q_values = model.predict(new_states)
```

Can someone help me understand where am I missing the point?